# MaterialTimePicker не срабатывает слушатель

Tags: android, material-design, listener

Если после показа диалога изменить ориентацию устройства, то при нажатии на кнопку “OK” слушатель не вызывается. Хотя если нажать на нее после показа диалога без поворотов экрана, все работает. Как это исправить?

```
  MaterialTimePicker timePicker = new MaterialTimePicker.Builder()
            .setHour(MainActivity.notificationTimeHour)
            .setMinute(MainActivity.notificationTimeMinutes).build();
    timePicker.addOnPositiveButtonClickListener(dialog -> Log.i(S.LOG_TAG, "no"));
    timePicker.show(getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager(), "");
```

Answer (score 0):

Пока что решил этот вопрос добавлением слушателя в диалог всякий раз после пересоздании фрагмента.

```
MaterialTimePicker timePicker = (MaterialTimePicker)
            getParentFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(S.TAG_DIALOG_TIME_PICKER);

    if (timePicker != null) {
        timePicker.clearOnPositiveButtonClickListeners(); // можно и не вызывать
        timePicker.addOnPositiveButtonClickListener(v -> setNotificationTime(timePicker));
    }
```